# Set TextView to time from TimePicker - Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have been using this tutorial [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html) to create a time picker.  I can select the time fine, but I can't get the time selected to show up in my TextView.  Java is not my preferred language so that is probably where I am falling down.

**Here is my java code:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

import java.util.Calendar;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    //code from: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html
    public void showTimePicker(View v) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
    }

    public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
            implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
            return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                    DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
        }

        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            // Do something with the time chosen by the user - how!?
        }
    }
}
```

In my XML I have the Choose Time button run the showTimePicker method on click like so:

```
android:onClick="showTimePicker"
```

I have tried just setting the text field inside the onTimeSet method but I get a nullpointerexception. Then I thought I should initialize it in onCreateDialog but there I don't know how to use findViewById to find the actual text view.  I'm sure this is probably simple but I have searched up and down without much luck. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it like that:

1) **Solution 1** (*better*):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        TextView resultText;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            resultText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id./*YOUR TEXT VIEW ID*/);
        }

        //code from: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html
        public void showTimePicker(View v) {
            DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment(resultText);
            newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
        }

        public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
                implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

             TextView mResultText;

             public TimePickerFragment(TextView textView) {
                mResultText = textView;
            }

            @Override
            public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
                return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                        DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
            }

            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                String time = /*CONVERT YOUR TIME FROM hourOfDay and minute*/;
                mResultText.setText(time);
            }
        }
    }
```

2) **Solution 2**:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public TextView mResultText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mResultText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id./*YOUR TEXT VIEW ID*/);
    }

    //code from: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html
    public void showTimePicker(View v) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
    }

    public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
            implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
            return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                    DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
        }

        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            String time = /*CONVERT YOUR TIME FROM hourOfDay and minute*/;
            mResultText.setText(time);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you say solution 1 is better? I'd say 2 is better because you only have to search for the TextView once; it's more efficient.

Comment: @NathanWalters If we talk about performance you are right, sol 2 is better. I've chosen sol 1 as better in case he(or another user) want to create "TimePickerFragment.class" outside the activity. Anyway, i'll update my sol 1 to be more efficient and thanks for your comment :)

Comment: Ah, yeah, I didn't consider that case. In that case, you could just move the ```findViewById()``` into ```onCreate()```. Then you get the benefits of more modular code *and* the performance boost!

Comment: Thanks a ton! It was frustrating being close and yet so stuck. This was extremely helpful.

Comment: mResultText is not static but is being accessed in a static block..code will complain..

Comment: Solution 1 should be avoided, as the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Fragment()) for fragments says: `It is strongly recommended that subclasses do not have other constructors with parameters, since these constructors will not be called when the fragment is re-instantiated`. This means for example that the app will crash with a NullPointerException if the screen orientation is changed while the dialog is displayed (`mResultText` will be null).

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use `findViewById`, as with `getActivity()` your fragment gets access to the activity it is running in and thus to the views inside the activity.

```
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
    textView.setText(String.format("%02d", hourOfDay), String.format("%02d", minute);
}
```

This simple solution should be preferred over passing a reference to the `TextView` to the fragment, as this reference will be lost on reinstantiation of the fragment (see [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26917864/)).