# Set TimePicker time from TextView text

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26917564/set-textview-to-time-from-timepicker-android) to create a TimePicker from a TextView. Right now, I want to show the TimePicker with the previous time selected.

So I open the first time the TimePicker and I set 08:15. The second time, I want to show on the TimePicker the preset time 08:15 and not the current hour:minute.

I think I need to change this part code:

```
   @Override
            public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
                return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                        DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
            }
```

Comment: save the time in shareprefernce

Comment: what you want ?

Comment: I wrote what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code..

```
public class displayTime extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView textView;
int hour,min;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView=findViewById(R.id.amTvData);
    Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    min = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showTime(hour,min);
         }
    });
}
void showTime(int hours,  int minte){
    TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
    mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(displayTime.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
            textView.setText( selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
            hour=selectedHour;
            min=selectedMinute;
        }
    }, hours, minte, false);//Yes 24 hour time
    mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
    mTimePicker.show();

}
}
```

Comment: Yes, perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively the [@Vinay Rathod's good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51305025/6733404), you maybe wanted save on the class instance, without storage nothing (many cases can be so), try as follow, saving on global variables:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...
    private int selectedHourOfDay, selectedMinuteOfDay;
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        selectedHourOfDay = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        selectedMinuteOfDay = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new TimePickerDialog(MyActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hour, int minute) {
                        textView.setText(hour + "h " + minute + "m");
                        selectedHourOfDay = hour;
                        selectedMinuteOfDay = minute;
                    }
                }, selectedHourOfDay, selectedMinuteOfDay, false).show();
             }
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // get minute and hour from shared preference
        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int hour = sharedpreferences.getInt("hourOfDay", 0);
        int minute = sharedpreferences.getInt("minute", 0);
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // save to preference
        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

        editor.putInt("hourOfDay", hourOfDay);
        editor.putInt("minute", minute);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

Comment: I didn't think about it. It could be a solution :)